# Vaadin large table scrolls inside table (and underneath header) instead of scrolling page

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin-grid

Vaadin Version: 23.3.3

I have a fairly complex Vaadin table, ~100 rows, each of which contains ~12 columns, each column containing a layout with ~10 elements. The table is not lazy in any way, and is configured to show all rows at once.

It takes the browser 5+ seconds just to render the table after the request is complete (a topic for a different question) but even once the table is rendered I experience some weirdness when scrolling.

When holding the mouse outside the table, or using the scroll bar, the page always scrolls as expected. But when I hold the mouse inside the table I get inconsistent results. If I have first scrolled the page *all the way to the bottom* then there appears to be no issue regardless of mouse position. But If I have yet to scroll to the bottom, then the table scrolls *in place*, pushing rows underneath the header (see screenshot). It's as if the browser/vaadin is not yet completely aware of the size of the table?

Is there something I need to be doing to force vaadin to render the entire page?

Edit: Upon some further testing I noticed even stranger inconsistencies. My table cells have two possible layouts depending on user actions. One is simple, containing: div > span > span. The other is more complex, containing a div > span > span + vaadin-icon + tooltip. The issue only appears when the table is rendered with the "simple" layout. Something about the added vaadin-icon and tooltip seems to make vaadin draw the table without scroll issues.

[image]

Comment: You should 1) remove all of your custom styles first and 2) specify your exact Vaadin version and 3) provide some code to reproduce or at least understand what is going on there

Comment: @ollitietavainen While following your suggestion I found some weirdness when deactivating specific styles as well. Working on compiling the details right now, but seems like it's definitely related.

Comment: @ollitietavainen So it looks like this is related to using table row/cell styles within Vaadin grid cells (i.e. display:table-row and display:table-cell). I suppose how to get those to work correctly is a separate issue. Unfortunately those styles are what I require, due to alignment requirements of my cell content.

Comment: Maybe you should create a new question about it, starting with your requirements and how you tried to solve it, and why it doesn't work.

Comment: The actual issue appears to be the usage of any table related CSS styles within a Vaadin Grid cell (ie display:table or display:grid). Unfortunately the only resolutions were 1) not use those styles or 2) not use the Vaadin Grid component. I had to go with #2 because there was no other way to create the layout I needed. Im now using the Vaadin html-table addon and creating a html <table> manually, which works fine because I don't need any of the complex features of the Grid.